# angularjs prevent default in ng-click async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, hyperlink, dom-events

If I have the following code, which doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<a href="#/otherpage" my-directive ng-click="preventClickAsync($event)">Click me!</a>
```

JS:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    controller: function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.preventClickAsync = function(e) {
        $http.get("/api/example").success(function(result) {
          if(result.notOk) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Is there another way to prevent the link from opening except changing the location from JS instead of using an `<a>`-Tag?

Answer (score 0):

use the `event.stopPropagation()` method. you can directly use it in the `ng-click` directive like this.

```
<a href="#/otherpage" my-directive ng-click="preventClickAsync($event); $event.stopPropagation(); ">Click me!</a>
```

Remove the `preventDefault` from the js code.

Comment: Won't work. `stopPropagation` is not the same a `preventDefault` and OP does want `preventDefault`.

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed to state that it's conditional, if the link is opened. I'll change it in the question.